# How to pass a method function to another Object?

Tags: oop, delphi

How to pass a method function to another Object? Is such a thing possible in Delphi?

For example, I am trying to create a PopupMenu in a DataModule, since this PopupMenu will be used in multiple places in the application.

The PopupMenu will use a particular function for example: `GetCustomer()` which returns `TCustomer`, on which various actions can be performed.

Each Form/Frame that is creating and using the DataModule, will want to pass it a custom implementation of `GetCustomer()`.

I was wanting to write something like this:

```
TGetCustomerFunc = function: TCustomer of object;
```

and then create a field/property on the DataModule:

```
TPopupDataModule = class(TDataModule)
public
  { Public declarations }
  GetCustomer: TGetCustomerFunc;
end;
```

`GetCustomer` would be assigned a method by each frame that is creating the `PopupDataModule`, with its own particular implementation.

However, `function: TCustomer of object;` is not valid syntax.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: "However, `function: TCustomer of object`; is not valid syntax.". Yes, it is perfectly valid.

Comment: @lurker: `function: TCustomer` is a parameterless function returning a `TCustomer` while `function: TCustomer of object` is a parameterless method returning a `TCustomer` (hence, it has a hidden `Self` parameter).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thanks, I wasn't familiar with that syntax.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: You are quite correct. My bad. Somehow it was not compiling at one point, probably because my syntax was not correct.

Comment: @RaelB the code shown is perfectly valid. So why do you think it is not? Are you getting a compiler error? If so, what is the error exactly? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: 3 possibilities, that come to my mind and you can investigate further: Events, anonymous methods and the strategy pattern

Comment: @DelphiCoder the code shown is essentially how events are implemented (though `procedure` is more commonly used than `function`)

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, I know that, I'm not a newbie! ;) the OP wanted suggestions about passing around functionality...

Answer (score 2):

Your initial question: How to pass a method function to another Object?

You can declare a type for your function or procedure prototype and then pass that around as you would any other variable.  Look at the use of `TNotifyEvent` all over the RTL, VCL and FMX for examples of how to do that.

Is such a thing possible?  Yes.

It's not clear to me exactly what your use case is, and so I'm not sure of the best example to give you.  You say that you want to use a `TDataModule` to create a `TPopupMenu`, which seems clear enough, but you then state that the `TCustomer` needs to be provided by `TFrame` and `TForm` objects that call it.

Why not just pass it the `TCustomer` object?  It seems a bit convoluted to pass a function to get an object instead.

If I have understood what you are looking for you will want something like this:

```pascal
interface

  type
  TCustomer = class(TObject);
  TGetCustomerFunc = function(): TCustomer of Object;

  TPopupDataModule = class(TDataModule)
  public
    function BuildPopupMenu(fnGetCustomer: TGetCustomerFunc): TPopupMenu;
    ...
  end;

implementation

  function TPopupDataModule.BuildPopupMenu(fnGetCustomer: TGetCustomerFunc): TPopupMenu;
  var
    pCustomer: TCustomer;
  begin
    if(Assigned(fnGetCustomer)) then
    begin
      pCustomer:=fnGetCustomer();
      ...
    end;
  end;
```

To call it you can then pass the address of a function in the object that's calling it.  So if you define in your form:

```pascal
  protected
    function GetTheCustomer(): TCustomer;
```

You can pass this routine to the TPopupDataModule like this:

```pascal
  { pPopupDM:=TPopupDataModule.Create(Application); // called previously }
  pPopupDM.BuildPopupMenu(Self.GetTheCustomer);    // in a Form method Self is the form
```